# Change text on radio button click

Tags: html, css

I have five thumbnail images in a row, below each image is a title and below the whole row is about 100 words of description text. What I intend to do is setup thumbnails to act as radio buttons to change the block of description text below the row to something relevant to that image.

So far I have setup the thumbnails with:

```
    <div id="thumbcontainer" style="left: 60px;">
      <img class="thumb"src="image1.jpg" >Title1
    </div> 
    <div id="thumbcontainer" style="left: 160px;">
       <img class="thumb"src="image2.jpg" >Title2
    </div>
    etc.

    <p class=”descrcontainer”>Description text of 100 words</p>
```

I am working through information in previous questions about how to use images as radio buttons but I cannot find any information about how to change the a block of text when a radio button is clicked. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can handle click of div and set text to descrcontainer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Errors

1. `#id`s must be unique, there's 2 `id="thumbcontainer"`
2. Each `class=”descrcontainer”`is a syntax error. A smart quote `”` does not work in code, use double straight quote `"`

#### Solution

- Add `<input id='rad*' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' style='display:none'>` in front of each `<p>`
- Add `display:none` to each `<p>`
- Make the `<div class="thumbcontainer">` into `<label for='chx*'>`
- Add The CSS etc.
- Use `label:focus` in CSS and add `tabindex='1'` to each `<label>` to highlight buttons.

#### Explaination

A `<label>` with `for` attribute with a value of an `#id` of a form control (e.g. `<input type='radio'>`) are linked. If you click a `<label for='rad0'>`, `<input id='rad0' type='radio'>` is clicked as well--like a remote button.

All `<input type='radio'>` that share the same `name` attribute will toggle in sync with each other. The behavior is basically only one radio can be checked.

A radio in the checked state can influence the styles of sibling elements that are after it and elements that are its descendants. In this demo:

```
.rad:checked + .descrcontainer {display:block;}
```

Any element with the class of `.rad` that is checked will make the next element with the class of `.descrcontainer` appear.

#### Demo

```css
.descrcontainer {
  display: none
}

.rad:checked+.descrcontainer {
  display: block;
}

label:focus {
  outline: 5px ridge cyan;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 6px 8px rgba(0, 128, 200, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<label for='rad0' class="thumbcontainer" style="display:inline-block;" tabindex='1'>
      <img class="thumb"src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/1112633650/92503d478bfa0e96f28a3fefe2edf5f1?v=1" width='128'><div style='text-align:center'>Dinosaurs</div>
    </label>
<label for='rad1' class="thumbcontainer" style="display:inline-block;" tabindex='1'>
       <img class="thumb"src="https://cdn-img.fimfiction.net/user/pcrx-1431833332-196431-256" width='128'><div style='text-align:center'>Demons</div>
    </label>

<input id='rad0' type='radio' class='rad' name='rad' style='display:none'>
<p class="descrcontainer">Angulomastacator blikanasaurus colepiocephale didanodon leshansaurus niobrarasaurus nuoersaurus ovoraptor owenodon parksosaurus plateosauravus silvisaurus titanosaurus xenotarsosaurus yaleosaurus yamaceratops yunxiansaurus. Campylodon clepsysaurus elrhazosaurus
  giraffatitan heterosaurus iguanodon magnirostris piatnitzkysaurus shanag shidaisaurus tochisaurus veterupristisaurus yimenosaurus. Airakoraptor astrodon balochisaurus brontosaurus ceratonykus elaphrosaurus fabrosaurus hadrosauravus hallopus indosuchus
  khateranisaurus moshisaurus nanotyrannosaurus neovenator peltosaurus puertasaurus rebbachisaurus suchosaurus tianyuraptor umarsaurus unquillosaurus wannanosaurus xixiposaurus.</p>

<input id='rad1' type='radio' class='rad' name='rad' style='display:none'>
<p class="descrcontainer">Adramelech andromalius azazel bali raj behemoth bhuta corson dagon eurynomos foras forneus gaki malthus mastema mephistopheles moloch ninurta onoskelis oray ose samael surgat tannin ziminiar. Agares aka manah azazel barbas davy jones drekavac eligos malthus
  incubus kokb'ael labal mammon marchosias naberius paimon surgat vapula. Ahriman alal azaz'el baal bael boruta cimeies crocell eblis familiars forcas jikininki labasu morax ad-dajjal medusa naberus serguthy shax shedim. Haborym alastor allocer allu ammut
  andhaka asag asb'el azaz'el azi dahaka bael balam davy jones gamigin imp ipos ipes jikininki kabhanda medusa naphula orcus paimonia serguthy vephar vine.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution looks good and your explanation is helpful. The only thing missing is that the selected button is not highlighted .

Comment: Thank you. After 55 years of programming in various computer languages I am finally learning HTML

Comment: @Ken if this answer has helped, upvote it by clicking the top triangle . If this answer has resolved your question accept it by clicking the check mark  ✅. If the answer has done both, by all means click both  ✅